# GridView Container.DataItem?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

A bit ashamed to ask this but, what is equivalent of Container.DataItem from DataGrid in GridView. I don't want to use Eval and I don't want to bind it to DataSource control. I want to be able to do this `<%#((MyType)Container.DataItem).MyAttribute %>` in template field.

**SOLVED**: Nevermind, it actually works, my tag was not closed in the aspx page correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Container.DataItem with a GridView - what you've got there looks fine. What error are you getting?

This link might also help:  [What's the deal with DataBinder.Eval and Container.DataItem](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2004/07/20/what-s-the-deal-with-databinder-eval-and-container-dataitem.aspx)?